# Warning: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ... on line 22

Tags: php, mysql

**Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не верно?**

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ... on line 22

```
 <?php function db_connect()
{   
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "Kokos";  
  $password = "12345"; 
  $db = 'shoop';

  $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
  if (!$connection || !mysql_connect($host, $user, $password))
  {
    return false;
  }
  return $connection;
}

function db_result_to_array($result)
{
$res_array = array();
$count = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $res_array[$count] = $row;
    $count++;
  }
return $res_array;
}

function get_products()
    {
    db_connect(); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    $result = db_result_to_array($result);
    return $result;
    }       
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в db_connect добавить mysql_select_db($db) перед `return $connection;`

Comment: shurik, Огромная благодарность!